# Snake game player movement pygame

Tags: python, game, pygame, snake-game

I've begun my journey with game development a little while ago, thought recreating snake would be cool, except I plan on adding other cool mechanics and stuff to it later. The player controller script utilizes a looot of if statements, I'm sure there's a much better and cleaner way to do this, any tips or help is greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Snake Class Script:

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(self.screen.get_rect().center, (16, 16))
        self.vel = 5
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, "orange", self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.rect.x >= 0:
                self.x_vel = -self.vel
                self.y_vel = 0
            else:
                self.x_vel = self.vel
                self.y_vel = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.rect.x <= 0:
                self.x_vel -= self.vel
                self.y_vel = 0
            else:
                self.x_vel = self.vel
                self.y_vel = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.rect.y >= 0:
                self.x_vel = 0
                self.y_vel = -self.vel
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
                self.y_vel = self.vel
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if self.rect.y <= self.screen.get_width():
                self.x_vel = 0
                self.y_vel = self.vel
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
                self.y_vel = -self.vel

        #Teleports player to other side of window if they go out of frame
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.x = self.screen.get_width()
        elif self.rect.x >= self.screen.get_width():
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.y <= 0:
            self.rect.y = self.screen.get_height()
        elif self.rect.y >= self.screen.get_height():
            self.rect.y = 0

        self.rect.x += self.x_vel
        self.rect.y += self.y_vel
```

Comment: Can you show how this class is instantiated and run? You're missing your `pygame` imports.